# How do I calculate the probability of overspending on a monthly advertising account?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm not sure if this is possible, I'm looking for a probability formula to calculate the probability of overspending or understanding on my monthly advertising budget.

Given that I have a $\$10,000$ budget and today is the 14th day of the month and I have spent $\$5900$ so far. What is the probability of overspending and underspending on this account?
I was able to calculate the daily and monthly spending with this reasoning but I can't come up with a formula for the probability.
Total budget - month to date spend/days left in a month = daily spend.
Total budget/days into month*total days in a month = forecasted monthly spend.

If this doesn’t makes sense I can retype and come up with a better explanation. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Presumably you have data on daily spending. You need to describe that as coming from some probability distribution in order to answer your question. If you spent a fixed amount per day, that would be $5900/14=\$421.43$ and if there are $16$ days remaining in the month, you'd need an additional $\$6742.86$, i.e., you'd be sure (probability $1$) to overspend.